# SBT Snapshot Resolution

Tags: sbt

I'm used to using Maven where SNAPSHOT resolution is cached and only invalidated every X amount of time (or forcibly with -U). With SBT, it resolves my snapshot every time which is painfully slow. Is there a way to tell SBT not to perform snapshot resolution every compile?

Answer (score 1):

See sbt 0.13.7 and newer's [Cached Resolution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cached-Resolution.html) feature for more detail.

In your *.sbt project definition file add:

```
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
```

**Edit:**
As per @samuel's comment below, the above setting does not (yet) affect snapshot dependencies as they are marked a as "changing" and always updated anyway. A workaround is to use sbt in `offline` mode **after** having resolved and downloaded all dependencies.

For example, in the sbt shell `set offline := true`.

Comment: "When a minigraph contains either a SNAPSHOT or dynamic dependency, the graph is considered dynamic, and it will be invalidated after a single task execution. Therefore, if you have any SNAPSHOT in your graph, your exeperience may degrade. (This could be improved in the future)"

Comment: @Samuel you are correct, it seems that sbt does not support cached resolution for snapshots yet. Updated the answer to include using offline mode during development as a workaround.